# Accessing the index file in public_html from SubDir

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I got a subDir with a '.htaccess' file, what I want is when this file recieves a request, the index in the root execute without any change of location in the file ..

Sub dir location :  'public_html/subdomains/news'

I wrote the '.htaccess' file as following

```
 RewriteEngine on

 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^news\.example\.com$ [OR]

 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.news\.example\.com$

 RewriteRule ^/?$  ../../index.php?url=news [L,QSA,NC]
```

**but didnt work**

As this subDir belongs to a subDomain, I dont  want its address changed , I want the user to access the location address:

```
 http://www.example.com/news
```

Through invoking the address:

```
 http://news.example.com
```

without them seeing it

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a sub-domain and point that sub-domain to folder.

like news.exmaple.com will be pointed to public_html/news (where news is the folder name)

No need to do any thing in .htaccess file.

Comment: I maked subdomain and have access to :
http://news.example.com
I want the following location called without the user seeing the location change and its access : http://www.example.com/news

Comment: try `RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ ./subdomains/sub/$1`

Answer (score 0):

For any sub domain request, use this:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.s\.co 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.s\.co 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/([a-zA-Z0-9-z\-]+) 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L]
```